# Adding menu resource file to different activities

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-menu

I want to add action bar items to my activities. But I'm only being able to have the menu resource file for the Main activity.
Can someone please help me set action bar items to my activities?

Answer (score 0):

In app/res/menu folder create new Menu resource file (xml file). In that file define your menu as you want it to be. And then in activity .java file include your menu in OnCreateOptionsMenu method.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu_file, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well. When I make a new menu resource file and make changes in it, my main activity's menu resource file changes as well. That is the problem.

Comment: You might be using rename refactoring. Check if you have that functionality enabled in your editor.

Comment: I don't know why that problem happened. The next day I tried it, everything worked fine.